# JSTree get normal XML data

Tags: javascript, xml, jstree

I'm using [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/xml_data#) to get a tree view of my xml file.
And now i want to convert tree back to the xml file, and save it, after it was edited.

How can i do that ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `$("#tree_container_id").jstree("get_xml")` to get the XML data.